# How to prevent nohup from "clogging" the command line?

Tags: bash, background-process, nohup

I want to write a bash script that runs two commands in the background. I am using nohup for this:

```
nohup cmd1 &
nohup cmd2 &
```

However, only the 1st command runs in the background.

When I run `nohup cmd1 &` manually in the command line. First, I type `nohup cmd1 &` then hit enter; this starts the process:

[image]

But, then I need to hit enter *again* to be able to type another command:

[image]

I think this is "clogging" up the command line, and is causing my bash script to get stuck at the first `nohup ... &` command.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you try something like: `sleep 5` in betweent he nohup commands?

Comment: @ryekayo it get's clogged up forever as opposed to 5 secs only.

Comment: There is no need to hit enter; the text which moved the cursor is disturbing but harmless.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is "clogged". The first command, running in the background, prints some output *after* your shell prints its next prompt. The shell is waiting for  you to type a command, even though the cursor is no longer on the same line as the prompt. That extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> is an empty command, causing the shell to print *another* prompt. It's harmless but unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Let me say something to `nohup` because I'm not sure if you are certain about what it is doing. In short, the `nohup` command is not necessary to run a process in background. The ampersand at the end of the line is doing it.

`nohup` prevents the background process from receiving `SIGHUP` (hup for *hang up*) if you close the terminal where the starting shell runs it. `SIGHUP` would effectively terminate the process.

If started with `nohup` the process will not receive that event and will continue running, owned by the init process (pid 1) if the terminal will being closed.

Furthermore the `nohup` command will redirect standard output of the controlled process to a file, meaning it will not appear on screen any more. By default this file is called `nohup.out`.